# When doesn't an accelerating charge emit light?

Tags: electromagnetism, synchrotron-radiation

An accelerating electron or proton emits light via synchrotron radiation, but an accelerating ring of charge [does not](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/272757/does-a-rotating-ring-of-charge-radiate-power-or-not) and [Larmor suggests](https://commons.princeton.edu/josephhenry/wp-content/uploads/sites/71/2021/01/Larmour-1897-On-the-theory-of-the-magnetic-influence-on-spectra-and-on-the-radiation-from-moving-ions-_-Zenodo.pdf) that a standing wave of charge wouldn't either {1}.

Are there any other special cases where accelerating charges don't emit light?

---

{1} "[S]teady motion which does not involve radiation is really a state of stationary undulation arising from the superposition of a wave-train traveling outwards on another travelling inwards". [(Page 511)](https://commons.princeton.edu/josephhenry/wp-content/uploads/sites/71/2021/01/Larmour-1897-On-the-theory-of-the-magnetic-influence-on-spectra-and-on-the-radiation-from-moving-ions-_-Zenodo.pdf)

Comment: I wouldn't call it an 'accelerating ring of charges'. The linked question is about a rotating ring wherein each individual charge may be accelerated (on their circular motion), but the charge and current density are both steady.

Comment: A more physical example would be the superconducting magnet in an NMR or MRI magnet. As with a synchrotron electrons are moving in a circle, each individually experiencing angular acceleration, but the system is [very stable](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.10.93).