# At what point are electromagnetic waves generated from an oscillating magnetic field?

Tags: photons

I recently learned about how an oscillating current, flowing through a looped wire can generate an oscillating magnetic field. I also came into some sources saying this is how antennas generate EM waves, but other sources saying that a simple oscillating current through a looped wire is not enough to generate EM waves.

At what point are electromagnetic waves generated and emitted as a result of an oscillating current flowing through a wire? How is a mere field being generated related to EM waves being broadcasted?

Comment: Who are those other sources? Were they implying a specific context, like radio technology or similar?

Comment: I'm trying to understand at what point electromagnetic waves are actually generated and broadcasted, as opposed to a mere magnetic/electromagnetic field around the wire. Or am I confused, and are these just one in the same?

Comment: As soon as one single charged particle is accelerated, it will create an electromagnetic wave. However, it might be so small that it is undetectable by conventional means. So the term "broadcast" might not be applicable.

Comment: How does this acceleration takes place? If an induction loop with an oscillating current being pumped through it generates an oscillating field, if I pump enough watts through it, will it begin to emit EM waves?

Comment: As long as the current is alternating, the loop will generate EM waves. The amplitude of the waves will depend on the current strength.

Comment: Not only an oscillating current accelerates electrons. A constant flow of electrons in a looped wire emits electromagnetic radiation. This is because a circular motion is an acceleration too.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I don't think this is true. To produce time-dependent E-fields and B-fields in Maxwell's equations requires time-varying current or charge densities. See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/if-you-run-an-electric-current-through-a-wire-loop-do-the-accelerated-charges-r

Comment: @RobJeffries Read about [Bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung)

Comment: @HolgerFiedler You said that a uniform current going around a *wire loop* would generate electromagnetic radiation. That is of course nothing like bremsstrahlung where individual electrons travel on partial segements of circular paths and there is both a $\rho(r,t)$ and a $J(r,t)$.

Comment: @RobJeffries there are different reasons for EM radiation. One is from thermal sources, it is most in the range of infrared and visible light. Second is from accelerations of electrons and other particles, including curved trajectory and one will get radiation up to gamma radiation. Third is from oscillating electrons, that we call better radio waves. Radio waves are modulations of EM radiation, which by the help of a generator we switch on and off.

Answer (score 1):

Your sources maybe talking about the efficiency with which electromagnetic radiation is produced compared with the dissipation of energy in the antenna.

All accelerating charges will produce electromagnetic waves. In your case an alternating current means that charges are being accelerated.

In general, the electromagnetic fields produced will have a number of terms in them, some of which will be important close to the antenna (known as the "near field"). These fields normally decay as $r^{-n}$, where $n\geq 2$ and become insignificant compared with other terms which become important far from the antenna (where far usually means many wavelengths of the radiation produced). 
This "far field" or "radiation field" has field strengths which decays as $r^{-1}$ and have the general form $f(r-ct)$, corresponding to an electromagnetic wave.

When radiation is generated, it has a Poynting vector that carries a certain amount of power away from the antenna. Often, for a simple small wire loop, this radiation power is negligible compared with the Ohmic resistance losses in the wire itself.